# Store procedure with the different type of data

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

First of all hi everyone, I am in stuck about my store procedure. Let me tell you what I want and show my code. I have a Configurator table which has IdType, TransactionType and Value. And I have seven different transaction type which are C,G,T,A,X,S,M. My value and IdType column come from UI in procedure. Only I want that to add my table these seven types for each IdType. If there is, then update it.

Here is my created store procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spConfTypeTransaction]
(
    @IdType INT,
    @Value INT,
    @TransactionType CHAR(1)
)
AS 
BEGIN
   DECLARE @CType CHAR
   SET  @CType = 'C'
   DECLARE @GType CHAR
   SET  @GType = 'G'
   DECLARE @TType CHAR
   SET  @TType = 'T'
   DECLARE @AType CHAR
   SET  @AType = 'A'
   DECLARE @XType CHAR
   SET  @XType = 'X'
   DECLARE @SType CHAR
   SET  @SType = 'S'
   DECLARE @MType CHAR
   SET  @MType = 'M'

IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM StockConfigurator where IdType = @IdType and Value = @Value and TransactionType = @CType) = 0
    INSERT INTO StockConfigurator
          (IdType, Value,TransactionType)
    VALUES
          (@IdType, @Value,@CType)
ELSE
    UPDATE StockConfigurator
    SET IdType = @IdType,
        Value = @Value,
        TransactionType = @TransactionType

IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM StockConfigurator where IdType = @IdType and Value = @Value and TransactionType = @GType) = 0
    INSERT INTO StockConfigurator
          (IdType, Value,TransactionType)
    VALUES
          (@IdType, @Value,@CType)
ELSE
    UPDATE StockConfigurator
    SET IdType = @IdType,
        Value = @Value,
        TransactionType = @TransactionType

IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM StockConfigurator where IdType = @IdType and Value = @Value and TransactionType = @TType) = 0
    INSERT INTO StockConfigurator
          (IdType, Value,TransactionType)
    VALUES
          (@IdType, @Value,@CType)
ELSE
    UPDATE StockConfigurator
    SET IdType = @IdType,
        Value = @Value,
        TransactionType = @TransactionType

IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM StockConfigurator where IdType = @IdType and Value = @Value and TransactionType = @AType) = 0
    INSERT INTO StockConfigurator
          (IdType, Value,TransactionType)
    VALUES
          (@IdType, @Value,@CType)
ELSE
    UPDATE StockConfigurator
    SET IdType = @IdType,
        Value = @Value,
        TransactionType = @TransactionType

IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM StockConfigurator where IdType = @IdType and Value = @Value and TransactionType = @XType) = 0
    INSERT INTO StockConfigurator
          (IdType, Value,TransactionType)
    VALUES
          (@IdType, @Value,@CType)
ELSE
    UPDATE StockConfigurator
    SET IdType = @IdType,
        Value = @Value,
        TransactionType = @TransactionType

IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM StockConfigurator where IdType = @IdType and Value = @Value and TransactionType = @SType) = 0
    INSERT INTO StockConfigurator
          (IdType, Value,TransactionType)
    VALUES
          (@IdType, @Value,@CType)
ELSE
    UPDATE StockConfigurator
    SET IdType = @IdType,
        Value = @Value,
        TransactionType = @TransactionType

IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM StockConfigurator where IdType = @IdType and Value = @Value and TransactionType = @MType) = 0
    INSERT INTO StockConfigurator
          (IdType, Value,TransactionType)
    VALUES
          (@IdType, @Value,@CType)
ELSE
    UPDATE StockConfigurator
    SET IdType = @IdType,
        Value = @Value,
        TransactionType = @TransactionType
END
```

I don't know how this procedure can be write more simply. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

If I follow you correctly, this can be the solution for you:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spConfTypeTransaction]
(
    @IdType INT,
    @Value INT,
    @TransactionType CHAR(1)
)
AS 
BEGIN
IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM StockConfigurator where IdType = @IdType and Value = @Value and TransactionType IN ('C', 'G', 'T', 'A', 'X', 'S', 'M')) = 0
    INSERT INTO StockConfigurator
          (IdType, Value,TransactionType)
    VALUES
          (@IdType, @Value,@CType)
ELSE
    UPDATE StockConfigurator
    SET IdType = @IdType,
        Value = @Value,
        TransactionType = @TransactionType
```

Answer (score 1):

if `@TransactionType` is always equal to `@*Type` and since all of your `insert/update` statements seem to do the exact same thing then all you need is this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spConfTypeTransaction]
(
    @IdType INT,
    @Value INT,
    @TransactionType CHAR(1)
)
AS 
BEGIN   

IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM StockConfigurator where IdType = @IdType and Value = @Value and TransactionType = @TransactionType) = 0
    INSERT INTO StockConfigurator
          (IdType, Value,TransactionType)
    VALUES
          (@IdType, @Value,@TransactionType)
ELSE
    UPDATE StockConfigurator
    SET IdType = @IdType,
        Value = @Value,
        TransactionType = @TransactionType
END
```

Comment: First of all thank you. I have a question then, do I have to write declare section as well?

Comment: @Cugureleuro You only need a `declare` block when you need to use local variables. If all the variable values you need are coming in as parameters, then the answer is no.

Comment: Okay, already Transaction Type must be local variable in my opinion beause only IdType and Value come as parameter.